# Filter a row with capitals and small letters, not just one or the the other but both

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a filter on rows with names and email addresses. I want the filter to show results with a match regardless of the capitals. 
eg:
search for Admin
should show admin@email.com and an Admin username.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'dataFilter'
})
export class DataFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(array: any[], query: string): any {
    if (query) {
      return _.filter(array, row => row.email.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) > -1 || row.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) > -1)
    }
    return array;
  }
}
```

I added the toLowerCase() - that solved the filter to show small letter searches, but if the user searches for Admin now, it will not find the email, just the username of: Admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
return _.filter(array, row => row.email.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1 || row.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can filter data irrespective of which case like below and also check this out for demo - 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wxocfg?file=src/app/filter.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
    if (!items) return [];
    if (!searchText) return items;
    searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
    return items.filter(it => {
      return it.email.toLowerCase().includes(searchText) || it.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were passing your query parameter as it was typed, so if it was present but with different cases, the indexOf method will return -1, so what you should do is convert the query parameter that you are passing into your transfrom function to lowercase too, so that there will be a match.

I solved your problem using JavaScript's inbuilt array filter since I couldn't figure out what the underscore was for. Cheers!

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'dataFilter'
})
export class DataFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(array: any[], query: string): any {
    // convert the query parameter to lowercase too
    query = query.toLowerCase();
    if(query && array.length){
        return array.filter(row => {
            return row.email.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) > -1 || 
               row.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) > -1;
        })
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With pattern requirement capitals and small letters, you should both `toLowerCase` or `toUpperCase`

```
return _.filter(array, row => row.email.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1 || row.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1)
```

OR

```
return _.filter(array, row => row.email.toUpperCase().indexOf(query.toUpperCase()) > -1 || row.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(query.toUpperCase()) > -1)
```

This demo use `toUpperCase` https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-filter-ignore-case